# Should I save images in an ArrayList as a Json object inside SQLite String Column

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-studio

Ok so I have an `ArrayList<Uri>` no specified size for it, in it there is the Uri of all the images added from both the gallery and camera,I have searched for ways to make it a Json object,and save it to the database but i have a feeling that this is not the optimal solution any better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GSON library (Link) for ArrayList to JSON conversion.

```
ArrayList<Domain> list = new ArrayList<Domain>();
list.add("something 1");
list.add("something 2");
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
```

Now you got your arraylist as a json String.Simply save this String to your SqLite DB or better just save to SharedPreference.